# Two way data binding not working after XHR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I watch property from vuex like this:

```
computed: {
    ticket() {
        return this.$store.getters['order/reservation'].offer_id
    }
},
watch: {
    ticket(newTicketId) {
        console.log('Caught change of ticket in InputDate', newTicketId)
        this.getAvailableDates(newTicketId)
    }
},
```

on its change I'm executing getAvailableDates(). This method is just doing http request using axios module:

```
    async getAvailableDates(id) {
        try {
            const response = await this.$axios.$get(
                `/valid_days?offer_id=${id}`
            )
            this.$set(this, 'availableDates', response)
            console.log('this.availableDates', this.availableDates) // works fine showing 30 length array
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error getting valid_days', e)
        }
    }
},
```

(i'm using nuxt)

as you can see I'm already trying to set it using $set method from vue instance. Previously i also tried just `this.availableDates = response` and `this.$set(this.data, 'availableDates', response)`.

Line where I console.log the response from API is working fine and in console I see the array perfectly fine:

[image]

but in vue devtools array is empty:

[image]

and in template where i do:

```
availableDates: {{ availableDates }}
```

it doesn't get updated as well

[image]

Never had something like this during my 2 year journey with Vue. this.$set was always working when I had problems with reactivity. Anyone got some idea what might be possible reason?

Comment: `$set` is used to update an item at a given index in data array, i think you could assign that data directly like `this.availableDates= response`

Comment: `$set` can be used to set property of object either. As you can see in docs `Vue.set(object, propertyName, value)`. Beside that I already tried direct assign which doesn't work as well as `$set` method which I mentioned in question.

Comment: did you try to not use `asyn/await`, i mean using `axios.get().then ... .catch()`

Comment: You should not use computed properties on getters, its waste... Its like using computed properties on computed properties

Comment: How you can watch store changes in component other way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's different for nuxt, but the Vue docs for $set have a warning

[Vue-set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

Warning:

> The target object cannot be a Vue instance, or the root data object of
> a Vue instance.

As Boussadjra Brahim commented you could use

```
this.availableDates= response
```

if availableDates is already an existing data property. $set only has to be used when adding new properties to an object and reactivity needs to be maintained.